# Using Extension methods in RoslynPad or Polyglot notebooks

Tags: c#, roslyn, dotnet-interactive, roslynpad

I try to understand an extension method similar to this code

```
var p = new Person("Tim");   
p.LastName = "Meier"; 

// reader.Get<bool>("IsDerivat");
var IsOlivia = p.Get<bool>("Olivia");
```

This is my code inside [RoslynPad](http://roslynpad.net):

```
public static class PersonExtensions
{
    public static T Get<T>(this Person person, string name)
    {
        return (T)person.NewFirstName(name);
    }
}

public class Person
{    
    public Person(string firstName)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
    }

    public string FirstName {get; private set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}

    public object NewFirstName(string name)
    {
        this.FirstName = name;
        return (object) this.FirstName;
    }        
}
```

But i get this error

> error CS1109: Extension methods must be defined in a top level static
>   class; PersonExtensions is a nested class

I found this question [extension-methods-must-be-defined-in-a-top-level-static-class-](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071296/error-extension-methods-must-be-defined-in-a-top-level-static-class-cs1109) and the answers are good.

Adding a `namespace Foo` returns

> error CS7021: Cannot declare namespace in script code

It seems that roslynpad adds stuff behind the scene. 
So how can i make sure that my extension method is defined in a top-level static class?

Comment: sounds like something you should open a github issue for.

Comment: This returns error `CS7021: Cannot declare namespace in script code` and there are several issues regarding this error 
[4478](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4478) or [1078](https://github.com/scriptcs/scriptcs/issues/1078)

Comment: var IsOlivia = p.Get<bool>("Olivia"); is incorrect by the way

Comment: Make sure you class is not within any other class

Comment: @viveknuna Could you elaborate why `p.Get<bool>("Olivia")`  is incorrect?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RoslynPad uses Roslyn's [script language syntax](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples), which does not allow extension methods in classes (because the entire script is actually a class, and C# doesn't allow extensions in nested classes).

Currently, your only option (besides referencing a compiled assembly that contains the extension class using `#r` directives) is to place the extension as a top-level method in the script. For example:

```
public static T Get<T>(this Person person, string name)
{
    return (T)person.NewFirstName(name);
}

var p = new Person("Tim");   
p.LastName = "Meier"; 

var IsOlivia = p.Get<bool>("Olivia"); // works
```

PS - I'm the author of RoslynPad.